# How can I remove specific patterns of text in a file using sed?

Tags: sed

I've searched for ways to remove patterns of text from text files. 
I found out about `sed` but I lack the experience to use it properly.

I have about 20 to 30 lines of similar text in a file called **psutildat.txt**

```
0.084849510927221, 'name': 'systemd'}
0.0, 'name': 'kthreadd'}
0.0, 'name': 'rcu_gp'}
0.0, 'name': 'rcu_par_gp'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/0:0H-kblockd'}
0.0, 'name': 'mm_percpu_wq'}
0.0, 'name': 'ksoftirqd/0'}
0.0, 'name': 'rcu_preempt'}
0.0, 'name': 'rcu_sched'}
0.0, 'name': 'rcu_bh'}
0.0, 'name': 'rcuc/0'}
0.0, 'name': 'rcub/0'}
0.0, 'name': 'migration/0'}
0.0, 'name': 'idle_inject/0'}
0.0, 'name': 'cpuhp/0'}
0.0, 'name': 'cpuhp/1'}
0.0, 'name': 'idle_inject/1'}
0.0, 'name': 'migration/1'}
0.0, 'name': 'rcuc/1'}
0.0, 'name': 'ksoftirqd/1'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/1:0H-kblockd'}
0.0, 'name': 'cpuhp/2'}
0.0, 'name': 'idle_inject/2'}
0.0, 'name': 'migration/2'}
0.0, 'name': 'rcuc/2'}
0.0, 'name': 'ksoftirqd/2'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/2:0H-kblockd'}
0.0, 'name': 'cpuhp/3'}
0.0, 'name': 'idle_inject/3'}
0.0, 'name': 'migration/3'}
0.0, 'name': 'rcuc/3'}
0.0, 'name': 'ksoftirqd/3'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/3:0H-kblockd'}
0.0, 'name': 'kdevtmpfs'}
0.0, 'name': 'netns'}
0.0, 'name': 'rcu_tasks_kthre'}
0.0, 'name': 'kauditd'}
0.0, 'name': 'khungtaskd'}
0.0, 'name': 'oom_reaper'}
0.0, 'name': 'writeback'}
0.0, 'name': 'kcompactd0'}
0.0, 'name': 'ksmd'}
0.0, 'name': 'khugepaged'}
0.0, 'name': 'crypto'}
0.0, 'name': 'kintegrityd'}
0.0, 'name': 'kblockd'}
0.0, 'name': 'edac-poller'}
0.0, 'name': 'devfreq_wq'}
0.0, 'name': 'watchdogd'}
0.0, 'name': 'kswapd0'}
0.0, 'name': 'kthrotld'}
0.0, 'name': 'irq/42-pciehp'}
0.0, 'name': 'acpi_thermal_pm'}
0.0, 'name': 'nvme-wq'}
0.0, 'name': 'nvme-reset-wq'}
0.0, 'name': 'nvme-delete-wq'}
0.0, 'name': 'ipv6_addrconf'}
0.0, 'name': 'kstrp'}
0.0, 'name': 'charger_manager'}
0.0, 'name': 'ata_sff'}
0.0, 'name': 'scsi_eh_0'}
0.0, 'name': 'scsi_tmf_0'}
0.0, 'name': 'scsi_eh_1'}
0.0, 'name': 'scsi_tmf_1'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/1:1H-kblockd'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/0:1H-kblockd'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/2:1H-kblockd'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/u9:0-hci0'}
0.0, 'name': 'jbd2/sda6-8'}
0.0, 'name': 'ext4-rsv-conver'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/3:1H-kblockd'}
0.31157690885410094, 'name': 'systemd-journald'}
0.008069119183860574, 'name': 'lvmetad'}
0.0, 'name': 'iprt-VBoxWQueue'}
0.0, 'name': 'iprt-VBoxTscThr'}
0.06064215337563928, 'name': 'systemd-udevd'}
0.0, 'name': 'irq/49-mei_me'}
0.0, 'name': 'cfg80211'}
0.0, 'name': 'kmemstick'}
0.0, 'name': 'rtsx_usb_ms_1'}
0.0, 'name': 'i915/signal:0'}
0.0, 'name': 'i915/signal:1'}
0.0, 'name': 'i915/signal:2'}
0.0, 'name': 'i915/signal:6'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/u9:1-hci0'}
0.0, 'name': 'nv_queue'}
0.0, 'name': 'nv_queue'}
0.0, 'name': 'nvidia-modeset/'}
0.0, 'name': 'nvidia-modeset/'}
0.0, 'name': 'irq/53-nvidia'}
0.0, 'name': 'nvidia'}
0.0, 'name': 'nv_queue'}
0.03920700854980107, 'name': 'systemd-timesyncd'}
0.04192971747687058, 'name': 'bluetoothd'}
0.049206775881947294, 'name': 'dbus-daemon'}
0.043513839034438305, 'name': 'systemd-logind'}
0.031979453943398344, 'name': 'avahi-daemon'}
0.025494456317105493, 'name': 'crond'}
0.054454178541390376, 'name': 'ModemManager'}
0.10326492403394574, 'name': 'NetworkManager'}
0.0031682431151354397, 'name': 'avahi-daemon'}
0.04772166192172756, 'name': 'sddm'}
0.17687707266217073, 'name': 'polkitd'}
0.9116619563802228, 'name': 'Xorg'}
0.0480681885124455, 'name': 'wpa_supplicant'}
0.08059218424125776, 'name': 'udisksd'}
0.06257280152392494, 'name': 'upowerd'}
0.04801868471377151, 'name': 'sddm-helper'}
0.05544425451487019, 'name': 'systemd'}
0.0024751899336995626, 'name': '(sd-pam)'}
0.027623119660087115, 'name': 'appimagelauncherfs'}
0.058860016623375595, 'name': 'appimagelauncherd'}
0.10564110637029732, 'name': 'kwalletd5'}
0.03707834520681945, 'name': 'startkde'}
0.04376135802780826, 'name': 'dbus-daemon'}
0.0010395797721538163, 'name': 'start_kdeinit'}
0.08376042735639319, 'name': 'kdeinit5'}
0.16430310779897694, 'name': 'klauncher'}
0.4153863746734605, 'name': 'kded5'}
0.11158156221117628, 'name': 'kaccess'}
0.024009342356885757, 'name': 'kwrapper5'}
0.13712552232695577, 'name': 'ksmserver'}
0.10395797721538162, 'name': 'kglobalaccel5'}
0.04004857312725892, 'name': 'dconf-service'}
1.9530733690849769, 'name': 'kwin_x11'}
0.12999697531790103, 'name': 'baloo_file'}
0.7622099881834433, 'name': 'krunner'}
2.7182040813901853, 'name': 'plasmashell'}
0.12420503087304405, 'name': 'polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1'}
0.08856229582777035, 'name': 'xembedsniproxy'}
0.08915634141185824, 'name': 'kactivitymanagerd'}
0.07291909544678911, 'name': 'gmenudbusmenuproxy'}
0.13168010447281672, 'name': 'kdeconnectd'}
0.1363334615481719, 'name': 'msm_kde_notifier'}
0.20722290124932738, 'name': 'octopi-notifier'}
0.1069777089344951, 'name': 'pulseaudio'}
0.024603387940973647, 'name': 'rtkit-daemon'}
0.04549399098139796, 'name': 'AppRun'}
0.2511822744718316, 'name': 'yakuake'}
0.02767262345876111, 'name': 'appimaged'}
0.6431533523724944, 'name': 'plank'}
0.029108233620306855, 'name': 'agent'}
0.17440188272847115, 'name': 'org_kde_powerdevil'}
0.0514839506209509, 'name': 'gvfsd'}
0.07217653846667924, 'name': 'kscreen_backend_launcher'}
0.043266320041068354, 'name': 'gvfsd-fuse'}
0.04237525166493651, 'name': 'bash'}
0.03376159069566203, 'name': 'gsettings-helper'}
0.021187625832468256, 'name': 'obexd'}
0.03920700854980107, 'name': 'at-spi-bus-launcher'}
0.029652775405720755, 'name': 'dbus-daemon'}
0.0, 'name': 'krfcommd'}
0.04366235043046028, 'name': 'at-spi2-registryd'}
0.07653287274999047, 'name': 'xdg-desktop-portal'}
0.044206892215874184, 'name': 'xdg-document-portal'}
0.030593347580526595, 'name': 'xdg-permission-store'}
0.10722522792786504, 'name': 'xdg-desktop-portal-gtk'}
0.03009830959378668, 'name': 'pipewire'}
0.559788955405493, 'name': 'bamfdaemon'}
0.04762265432437958, 'name': 'cupsd'}
0.5815211230233752, 'name': 'tilix'}
0.05093940883553699, 'name': 'bash'}
0.07816649810623218, 'name': 'file.so'}
0.04509796059200603, 'name': 'gvfsd-metadata'}
0.10123526828831211, 'name': 'baloorunner'}
4.453361728712252, 'name': 'firefox'}
2.0012405651947702, 'name': 'WebExtensions'}
2.1960875167756, 'name': 'Web Content'}
2.1629694754627, 'name': 'Web Content'}
0.02579147910914944, 'name': 'mount.ntfs'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/0:2-events'}
6.8419695185310045, 'name': 'Web Content'}
1.6792183548204571, 'name': 'Discord'}
0.47716711541860163, 'name': 'Discord'}
1.443184242742867, 'name': 'Discord'}
3.410663217241975, 'name': 'Discord'}
2.369845850121309, 'name': 'Web Content'}
2.7086993520447793, 'name': 'Web Content'}
0.13663048434021585, 'name': 'gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor'}
0.08786924264633447, 'name': 'gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor'}
0.09247309592301564, 'name': 'gvfs-afc-volume-monitor'}
0.0691073029488918, 'name': 'gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor'}
0.09583935423284705, 'name': 'gvfsd-trash'}
0.096136377024891, 'name': 'gvfsd-network'}
0.096136377024891, 'name': 'gvfsd-dnssd'}
1.8358978776236397, 'name': 'code-oss'}
0.6873602445883684, 'name': 'electron'}
1.4864505627839353, 'name': 'electron'}
2.6789970728403842, 'name': 'electron'}
1.2712080461494213, 'name': 'electron'}
2.4350918567736293, 'name': 'electron'}
0.5952336752560708, 'name': 'python'}
0.3155372127480202, 'name': 'python'}
0.30712156697344173, 'name': 'python'}
0.2936565337341161, 'name': 'python'}
0.23677666905770012, 'name': 'python'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/2:1-events'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/3:2-events'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/u8:0+events_unbound'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/0:0-pm'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/1:2-events'}
2.167028786953967, 'name': 'Web Content'}
0.8931475356761501, 'name': 'Web Content'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/u8:2-events_power_efficient'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/1:0-events'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/3:1-pm'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/u8:4-phy0'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/3:0-events'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/2:0-mm_percpu_wq'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/1:1-events'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/u8:1-events_power_efficient'}
0.004356334283311229, 'name': 'xclip'}
0.0, 'name': 'kworker/1:3-events'}
0.2534099454121612, 'name': 'tags.so'}
0.2534099454121612, 'name': 'tags.so'}
0.046038532766811864, 'name': 'ilumi.sh'}
0.14875891501534372, 'name': 'python3'}
```

I specifically want to remove the **, 'name': ** parts. The amount of commands doesn't matter. Also I want to remove the curly brackets
 at the end of each line.

Is there a way to do it? It will all be put in a bash script anyways.

EDIT:
Added the whole contents of the file. It changed a bit since the last time I ran the script as the memory usage does change.

EDIT2:
Very odd. sometimes it works and sometimes it just garbles like this

```
 'memory_percent': 0.084849510927221}
, 'memory_percent': 0.0}
'memory_percent': 0.0}
p', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
:0H-kblockd', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
_wq', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
/0', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
pt', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
'memory_percent': 0.0}
'memory_percent': 0.0}
'memory_percent': 0.0}
/0', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
ct/0', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
 'memory_percent': 0.0}
 'memory_percent': 0.0}
ct/1', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
/1', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
'memory_percent': 0.0}
/1', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
:0H-kblockd', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
 'memory_percent': 0.0}
ct/2', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
/2', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
'memory_percent': 0.0}
/2', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
:0H-kblockd', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
 'memory_percent': 0.0}
ct/3', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
/3', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
'memory_percent': 0.0}
/3', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
:0H-kblockd', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
memory_percent': 0.0}
_kthre', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
 'memory_percent': 0.0}
d', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
r', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
0', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
emory_percent': 0.0}
d', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
'memory_percent': 0.0}
yd', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
 'memory_percent': 0.0}
er', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
q', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
 'memory_percent': 0.0}
, 'memory_percent': 0.0}
iehp', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
mal_pm', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
 'memory_percent': 0.0}
t-wq', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
te-wq', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
conf', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
memory_percent': 0.0}
anager', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
 'memory_percent': 0.0}
', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
0', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
1', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
:1H-kblockd', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
:1H-kblockd', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
:1H-kblockd', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
9:0-hci0', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
-8', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
conver', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
:1H-kblockd', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
ournald', 'memory_percent': 0.3137550759957565}
 'memory_percent': 0.008069119183860574}
WQueue', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
TscThr', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
devd', 'memory_percent': 0.06064215337563928}
i_me', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
, 'memory_percent': 0.0}
', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
ms_1', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
al:0', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
al:1', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
al:2', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
al:6', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
9:1-hci0', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
, 'memory_percent': 0.0}
, 'memory_percent': 0.0}
deset/', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
deset/', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
idia', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
'memory_percent': 0.0}
, 'memory_percent': 0.0}
imesyncd', 'memory_percent': 0.03920700854980107}
d', 'memory_percent': 0.04192971747687058}
on', 'memory_percent': 0.049206775881947294}
ogind', 'memory_percent': 0.043513839034438305}
mon', 'memory_percent': 0.031979453943398344}
memory_percent': 0.025494456317105493}
ger', 'memory_percent': 0.054454178541390376}
nager', 'memory_percent': 0.10326492403394574}
mon', 'memory_percent': 0.0031682431151354397}
emory_percent': 0.04772166192172756}
 'memory_percent': 0.17687707266217073}
emory_percent': 0.9116619563802228}
icant', 'memory_percent': 0.0480681885124455}
 'memory_percent': 0.08059218424125776}
 'memory_percent': 0.06257280152392494}
er', 'memory_percent': 0.04801868471377151}
 'memory_percent': 0.05544425451487019}
, 'memory_percent': 0.0024751899336995626}
auncherfs', 'memory_percent': 0.027623119660087115}
auncherd', 'memory_percent': 0.058860016623375595}
', 'memory_percent': 0.10564110637029732}
, 'memory_percent': 0.03707834520681945}
on', 'memory_percent': 0.04376135802780826}
init', 'memory_percent': 0.0010395797721538163}
, 'memory_percent': 0.08376042735639319}
', 'memory_percent': 0.16430310779897694}
memory_percent': 0.4153863746734605}
 'memory_percent': 0.11158156221117628}
', 'memory_percent': 0.024009342356885757}
', 'memory_percent': 0.13712552232695577}
cel5', 'memory_percent': 0.10395797721538162}
vice', 'memory_percent': 0.04004857312725892}
, 'memory_percent': 1.9548555058372403}
e', 'memory_percent': 0.13039300570729295}
 'memory_percent': 0.7622099881834433}
ll', 'memory_percent': 2.7184516003835557}
e-authentication-agent-1', 'memory_percent': 0.12420503087304405}
proxy', 'memory_percent': 0.08856229582777035}
managerd', 'memory_percent': 0.08915634141185824}
menuproxy', 'memory_percent': 0.07291909544678911}
td', 'memory_percent': 0.13168010447281672}
otifier', 'memory_percent': 0.1363334615481719}
tifier', 'memory_percent': 0.20722290124932738}
o', 'memory_percent': 0.1069777089344951}
mon', 'memory_percent': 0.024603387940973647}
'memory_percent': 0.04549399098139796}
 'memory_percent': 0.2511822744718316}
', 'memory_percent': 0.02767262345876111}
memory_percent': 0.6431533523724944}
memory_percent': 0.029108233620306855}
owerdevil', 'memory_percent': 0.17440188272847115}
memory_percent': 0.0514839506209509}
ackend_launcher', 'memory_percent': 0.07217653846667924}
e', 'memory_percent': 0.043266320041068354}
emory_percent': 0.04237525166493651}
-helper', 'memory_percent': 0.03376159069566203}
memory_percent': 0.021187625832468256}
s-launcher', 'memory_percent': 0.03920700854980107}
on', 'memory_percent': 0.029652775405720755}
, 'memory_percent': 0.0}
egistryd', 'memory_percent': 0.04366235043046028}
op-portal', 'memory_percent': 0.07653287274999047}
ent-portal', 'memory_percent': 0.044206892215874184}
ssion-store', 'memory_percent': 0.030593347580526595}
op-portal-gtk', 'memory_percent': 0.10722522792786504}
, 'memory_percent': 0.03009830959378668}
n', 'memory_percent': 0.559788955405493}
memory_percent': 0.04762265432437958}
memory_percent': 0.5815211230233752}
emory_percent': 0.05093940883553699}
 'memory_percent': 0.07816649810623218}
adata', 'memory_percent': 0.04509796059200603}
er', 'memory_percent': 0.10123526828831211}
 'memory_percent': 5.3409153351382415}
ions', 'memory_percent': 2.290936795034967}
nt', 'memory_percent': 2.1626229488719817}
nt', 'memory_percent': 2.1638110400401573}
s', 'memory_percent': 0.02579147910914944}
:2-events', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
nt', 'memory_percent': 6.782812479115585}
 'memory_percent': 1.6736244255702963}
 'memory_percent': 0.47716711541860163}
 'memory_percent': 1.4448178680991086}
 'memory_percent': 3.3573971298687604}
nt', 'memory_percent': 2.3614302043467306}
nt', 'memory_percent': 2.557415743297062}
ks2-volume-monitor', 'memory_percent': 0.13663048434021585}
to2-volume-monitor', 'memory_percent': 0.08786924264633447}
volume-monitor', 'memory_percent': 0.09247309592301564}
volume-monitor', 'memory_percent': 0.0691073029488918}
sh', 'memory_percent': 0.09583935423284705}
work', 'memory_percent': 0.096136377024891}
sd', 'memory_percent': 0.096136377024891}
, 'memory_percent': 1.8372839839865114}
, 'memory_percent': 0.6873602445883684}
, 'memory_percent': 1.487836669146807}
, 'memory_percent': 2.7911726806356487}
, 'memory_percent': 1.2875442997118383}
, 'memory_percent': 2.437468039109981}
'memory_percent': 0.5952336752560708}
'memory_percent': 0.3155372127480202}
'memory_percent': 0.30712156697344173}
'memory_percent': 0.2936565337341161}
'memory_percent': 0.23677666905770012}
:1-events', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
:2-events', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
:0-pm', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
:2-events', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
nt', 'memory_percent': 2.1673753135446847}
nt', 'memory_percent': 0.8931475356761501}
8:4-events_power_efficient', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
:1-rtl8723be_pci', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
8:1-events_unbound', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
 'memory_percent': 0.2534099454121612}
 'memory_percent': 0.2534099454121612}
8:2-events_unbound', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
:2-mm_percpu_wq', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
:0-mm_percpu_wq', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
:1-events', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
:3-events', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
:0-events', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
8:0-events_unbound', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
:0-events', 'memory_percent': 0.0}
, 'memory_percent': 0.04678108974692173}
 'memory_percent': 0.14910544160606165}
```

EDIT3:
Figured out why it went garbled. apparently the order in which my `psutil` outputs is kinda random. so pretty much the memory usage part and the process name part switch places and that's why it looked garbled... I apologize for this. And also thank you very much for the help!

Comment: I used the parentheses  to show where the section begins and where it ends. I'll edit it now to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are looking for is the substitute:

`sed 's/pattern1/pattern2/g'`

Which will replace all ocurrences of pattern1 with pattern2.
If you are sure this pattern will only appear once per line, you can omit the last "g" in the command.

So, in your case:

`sed 's/, '\''name'\'': //g' filename`

will output the desired file with changes made.

Since the single quote is part of the pattern, remember to escape it properly by using `'\''` to [end up with a single quote in the regex.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33005)

To remove the curly braces, you can do the same, with a regular expression (dollar symbol) setting the end of a line:

`sed 's/}$//g' filename`

Comment: it kinda worked but something went wrong. It went a bit rambo on the lining so to say.

Comment: ` 'memory_percent': 0.084849510927221
, 'memory_percent': 0.0
'memory_percent': 0.0
p', 'memory_percent': 0.0
:0H-kblockd', 'memory_percent': 0.0`

Comment: It worked on my terminal with your example. Maybe your file contains other special characters?

Comment: I'll edit it with the whole file and the complete result

Comment: that's odd. so I ran it again and it worked the right way. holy s**t

Comment: here it hoes garbled again

Comment: Thank you for the syntax explanation sir. Also, yes your command was working right. my s**tty python skills were the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "s/, 'name'://g" psutildat.txt
```

Will replace all occurrences of ", 'name':" with an empty string, effectively removing it.

Comment: `g` and `<` are unnecessary.

Comment: @Cyrus isn't the `g` something like, do it for every line?

Comment: @Iverol : No, `g` in `sed` is a per-line directive, for `global` (for each line that matches the pattern). In this case, there is no need to perform the substitution more than once. If you get into the habit of always using a trailing `g` for global, you'll shoot yourself in the foot one day ;-), so ... don't do that! Good luck to all.